# how to automaticaly start a service in linux if it fails

Tags: linux, services

An interviewer asked me this question in an interview.

He asked, suppose a service xyz stops due to any reason and you want it running all the time, what will you do so that it will start automatically

Comment: Do you have any ideas yourself ?

Comment: The possible solution that I thought was, there might be some command similar to chkconfig or to add an entry of that process in some file though preferred to say no rather than to bluff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to be mean but a simple google search will give you a lot of options to do this. Here is one I found:

The easiest way would be to add it to **/etc/inittab**, which is designed to do this sort of thing:

> **respawn** If the process does not exist, start the process. Do not wait
>   for its termination (continue scanning the /etc/inittab file). Restart
>   the process when it dies. If the process exists, do nothing and
>   continue scanning the /etc/inittab file.

For example, you could do this:

```
# Run my stuff
myprocess:2345:respawn:/bin/myprocess
```

Link: [How to automatically restart a linux background process if it fails?](https://superuser.com/questions/507576/how-to-automatically-restart-a-linux-background-process-if-it-fails)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I did google search but I guess I dint framed the question correctly and all I got is how to use service, chkconfig and systemctl commands